# Пропадает текст из яйчейки в DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Собственно не могу понять почему происходит непонятное явление, при инициализации грида текст в ячейке появляется и сразу же исчезает.

```
DataSet ds = core.getBid(); 

dg_bid.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
dg_bid.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
dg_bid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
dg_bid.ReadOnly = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn navi;
navi = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
navi.Name = "Navigation";
navi.DataPropertyName = "Navigation";
navi.HeaderText = "Маршрут";
navi.ValueType = typeof(string);
navi.ReadOnly = false;
navi.Visible = true;
navi.FillWeight = 250;


dg_bid.Columns["id"].Visible = false;
dg_bid.Columns["num"].HeaderText = "#";
dg_bid.Columns["create_date"].ValueType = typeof(DateTime);
dg_bid.Columns["create_date"].HeaderText = "Дата";
dg_bid.Columns.Add(navi);
for (int i = 0; i < dg_bid.Rows.Count; i++)
{        
    //Маршрут
    string bidID = dg_bid.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
    string nav_text = core.navi(bidID).ToString();
    dg_bid.Rows[i].Cells["Navigation"].Value = nav_text;
}
```

Остальные колонки загружается нормально, непонятное только с созданной колонкой "Navigation", у грида стоит ReadOnly = false; Из-за чего может это происходить?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dg_bid.Rows.Count; i++)
{        
    //Маршрут
    string bidID = dg_bid.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
    string nav_text = core.navi(bidID).ToString();

    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].BeginEdit();
    dataSet11.Tables[i].Rows[0]["Navigation"] = nav_text;
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].EndEdit();
}
```

Comment: Столбец "Navigation" создается программно, его нет в таблице. Поэтому вы дает ошибку: "Столбец "Navigation" не принадлежит таблице Table.". Но спасибо что толкнули в сторону решения данного вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

После определения источника данных `DataSet ds = core.getBid();` 
Добавляем новую колонку в ds, т.к. ее не существует `ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("navigation");`. Далее программно добавляем колонку в DataGridView:

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn navi = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
navi.Name = "Navigation";
navi.DataPropertyName = "navigation"; 
navi.HeaderText = "Маршрут";
navi.ReadOnly = true;
```

`navi.DataPropertyName = "navigation";`  Название колонки должно соответствовать названию созданной ранее колонки в Dataset для того чтобы данные данные из DataSet выводились в этот столбец сами.

Теперь записываем данные в эту колонку

```
for (int i = 0; i < dg_bid.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    //Маршрут
    string bidID = dg_bid.Rows[i].Cells["id"].Value.ToString();
    string nav_text = core.navi(bidID).ToString();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].BeginEdit();
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["navigation"] = nav_text;
    ds.Tables[0].Rows[i].EndEdit();
}
```

Теперь при выводе в гриде текст не пропадает в колонке.